# modemmanager gsm registration timeout

Tags: yocto, networkmanager

Our OS is Yocto 2.4 Rocko running on i.MX6.
For testing SIMCOM SIM7600JC-H LTE module, We installed NetworkManager v1.4.4, ModemManager v1.6.4, and pppd v2.4.7.

We test the SIM7600JC-H LTE function, it worked well in Taiwan but worked failed in Japan. We tried to find the difference between the two tests. And we found the main reason is that if we don't set APN to LTE module before the modem manager starts to run in Japan, it would work failed. So if I set APN to LTE module and then start modem manager service in Japan, it would work well and connect to the internet.

We think if the modem is in register status is the root cause.
If the modem isn't in register status at first and then starting the modem manager, it would work failed to connect to the internet.

In Taiwan, we don't need to set APN to the LTE module, and then the LTE module would be in register status after a SIM card is inserted and powered on.

In Japan, we need to set APN to the LTE module, and then the LTE module would be in register status after a SIM card is inserted and powered on.

The log is about modem manager works failed

```
Simple  connect state   (4/8):  Wait    to  get fully   enabled                             
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'ATX4<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT&C1<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
loading power   state...                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CFUN?<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CFUN: 1<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                    
No  need    to  change  power   state:  already in  'on'    power   state                       
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+IFC=1,1<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>ERROR<CR><LF>'                                                     
Got failure code    100:00:00   Unknown error                                           
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CSCS=?<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                 
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CSCS="UCS2"<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CSCS?<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CSCS: UCS2<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                 
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
Modem   has 3GPP    capabilities,   enabling    the Modem   3GPP    interface...                                
Checking    indicator   support...                                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CIND=?<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CIND: ("battchg",(0-5)),("signal",(0-5)),("service",(0-1)),("call",(0-1)),("roam",(0-1)),("smsfull",(0-1)),("GPRS coverage",(0-1)),("callsetup",(0-3))<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                             
Modem   supports    signal  quality indications via CIND    at  index   '2'(min:    0,  max:    5)              
Modem   supports    roaming indications via CIND    at  index   '5'                             
Modem   supports    service indications via CIND    at  index   '3'                             
(ttyUSB2)   Setting 3GPP    unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB3)   Setting 3GPP    unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMER=3,0,0,1<CR>'                                                       
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB3):  --> 'AT+CMER=3,0,0,1<CR>'                                                       
(ttyUSB3):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CNSMOD=1<CR>'                                                       
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+AUTOCSQ=1,1<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   setting up  3GPP    unsolicited registration    messages    handlers                                    
(ttyUSB3)   setting up  3GPP    unsolicited registration    messages    handlers                                    
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CREG=2<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB3):  --> 'AT+CREG=2<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB3):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CGREG=2<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB3):  --> 'AT+CGREG=2<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
Modem   has 3GPP/USSD   capabilities,   enabling    the Modem   3GPP/USSD   interface...                                
(ttyUSB2)   Setting unsolicited result  code    handlers                                            
(ttyUSB3)   Setting unsolicited result  code    handlers                                            
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CUSD=1<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
Modem   has location    capabilities,   enabling    the Location    interface...                                    
Need    to  enable  the following   location    sources:    '3gpp-lac-ci'                                   
Running registration    checks  (CS:    'yes',  PS: 'yes',  EPS:    'no')                               
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
Modem   has messaging   capabilities,   enabling    the Messaging   interface...                                    
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CREG?<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CREG: 2,2<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                  
Modem   /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP    Registration    state   changed (unknown    ->  searching)                              
Will    start   keeping track   of  state   for subsystem   '3gpp'                              
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  4   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMGF=?<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CMGF: (0-1)<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                    
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  4   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CGREG?<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CGREG:    2,2<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                  
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMGF=0<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
Successfully    set preferred   SMS mode:   'PDU'                                           
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CPMS="SR","ME","ME"<CR>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CPMS: 0,20,1,23,1,23<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                   
Listing SMS parts   in  storage 'me'                                            
Locking SMS storages    to: mem1    (ME),   mem2    (none)...                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CPMS="ME"<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CPMS: 1,23,1,23,1,23<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMGL=4<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CMGL: 0,1,"",151<CR><LF>0891180945123470F42414D0B01A0C87C3C160B11A0E0008918051518543638096FB8A71756A53F7FF1A00380031003800300032003100350038003400380038003525C630AD30FCFF1A0053004100430046002D005300500043004C002D0043003400390042002D0035004500410032002D003800320037003525C600550052004CFF1A0068007400740070003A002F002F0077006200720074002E006A0070<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                   
Parsing PDU (0)...                                                      
SMSC    address parsed: '+8190542143074'                                                    
Deliver type    PDU detected                                                    
Number  parsed: '05088800158'                                                       
PID:    0                                                           
user    data    encoding    is  UCS2                                                
user    data    length: 128 elements                                                
user    data    length: 128 bytes                                               
Decoding    SMS text    with    '128'   elements                                            
Converting  SMS part    text    from    UCS-2BE to  UTF8...                                 
Got UTF-8   text:   '????:818021584885???:SACF-SPCL-C49B-5EA2-8275?URL:http://wbrt.jp'                                                  
Correctly   parsed  PDU 0                                                   
SMS part    at  'me/0'  is  from    a   singlepart  SMS                             
Added   received    SMS at  '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/0'                                              
Listing SMS parts   in  storage 'sm'                                            
Locking SMS storages    to: mem1    (SM),   mem2    (none)...                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CPMS="SM"<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CPMS: 4,20,1,23,1,23<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMGL=4<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CMGL: 0,1,"",161<CR><LF>0891180945123460F64012D04E2A15447C0E9FCD270008913010116561638B0608049E6A0401301030C930B330E2304B3089306E304A77E53089305B3011000D000A672C30E130FC30EB306F682A5F0F4F1A793E004E0054005430C930B330E2304B3089901A4FE16599712165993067914D4FE1305730663044307E30593002000D000A000D000A304A5BA269D8306E7AEF672B304C30C930B330E2306E30CD30C330C830EF30FC30AF<CR><LF>+CMGL:    1,1,"",161<CR><LF>0891180945123460F64012D04E2A15447C0E9FCD270008913010116561638B0608049E6A0402306B6B633057304F3064306A304C3063305F305330683092304A77E53089305B3044305F3057307E30593002000D000A000D000A0073007030E230FC30C93092305452297528306E969B306F300130A230AF30BB30B930DD30A430F330C83092300C00730070006D006F00640065002E006E0065002E006A0070300D306B8A2D5B9A3057<CR><LF>+CMGL:    2,1,"",161<CR><LF>0891180945123460F64012D04E2A15447C0E9FCD270008913010116561638B0608049E6A04033066304F3060305530443002000D000A000D000A3088308A5FEB9069306B3054522975283044305F3060304F305F3081306E8A2D5B9A65B96CD530016CE8610F4E8B98053001554F5408305B51487B49306B306430443066306F30014E0B8A1800550052004C3088308A305478BA8A8D304F3060305530443002FF08901A4FE165996709<CR><LF>+CMGL:    3,1,"",145<CR><LF>0891180945123460F64412D04E2A15447C0E9FCD270008913010116561637B0608049E6A04046599FF09000D000A0068007400740070003A002F002F0073006500720076006900630065002E0073006D0074002E0064006F0063006F006D006F002E006E0065002E006A0070002F0073006900740065002F006D00610069006C002F007300720063002F00630063006E002E00680074006D006C<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                       
Parsing PDU (0)...                                                      
SMSC    address parsed: '+8190542143066'                                                    
Deliver type    PDU detected                                                    
Number  parsed: 'NTT    DOCOMO'                                                 
PID:    0                                                           
user    data    encoding    is  UCS2                                                
user    data    length: 139 elements                                                
user    data    length: 139 bytes                                               
Decoding    SMS text    with    '132'   elements                                            
Converting  SMS part    text    from    UCS-2BE to  UTF8...                                 
Got UTF-8   text:   '????????????#015#012?????????NTT???????????????????#015#012#015#012?????????????????'                                                  
Correctly   parsed  PDU 0                                                   
SMS part    at  'sm/0'  is  from    a   multipart   SMS (reference: '40554',    sequence:   '1')                
Added   received    SMS at  '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SMS/1'                                              
Parsing PDU (1)...                                                      
SMSC    address parsed: '+8190542143066'                                                    
Deliver type    PDU detected                                                    
Number  parsed: 'NTT    DOCOMO'                                                 
PID:    0                                                           
user    data    encoding    is  UCS2                                                
user    data    length: 139 elements                                                
user    data    length: 139 bytes                                               
Decoding    SMS text    with    '132'   elements                                            
Converting  SMS part    text    from    UCS-2BE to  UTF8...                                 
Got UTF-8   text:   '??????????????????????#015#012#015#012sp?????????????????????spmode.ne.jp?????'                                                    
Correctly   parsed  PDU -1                                                  
SMS part    at  'sm/1'  is  from    a   multipart   SMS (reference: '40554',    sequence:   '2')                
Parsing PDU (2)...                                                      
SMSC    address parsed: '+8190542143066'                                                    
Deliver type    PDU detected                                                    
Number  parsed: 'NTT    DOCOMO'                                                 
PID:    0                                                           
user    data    encoding    is  UCS2                                                
user    data    length: 139 elements                                                
user    data    length: 139 bytes                                               
Decoding    SMS text    with    '132'   elements                                            
Converting  SMS part    text    from    UCS-2BE to  UTF8...                                 
Got UTF-8   text:   '??????#015#012#015#012??????????????????????????????????????URL??????????(????'                                                    
Correctly   parsed  PDU -2                                                  
SMS part    at  'sm/2'  is  from    a   multipart   SMS (reference: '40554',    sequence:   '3')                
Parsing PDU (3)...                                                      
SMSC    address parsed: '+8190542143066'                                                    
Deliver type    PDU detected                                                    
Number  parsed: 'NTT    DOCOMO'                                                 
PID:    0                                                           
user    data    encoding    is  UCS2                                                
user    data    length: 123 elements                                                
user    data    length: 123 bytes                                               
Decoding    SMS text    with    '116'   elements                                            
Converting  SMS part    text    from    UCS-2BE to  UTF8...                                 
Got UTF-8   text:   '?)#015#012http://service.smt.docomo.ne.jp/site/mail/src/ccn.html'                                                  
Correctly   parsed  PDU -3                                                  
SMS part    at  'sm/3'  is  from    a   multipart   SMS (reference: '40554',    sequence:   '4')                
Listing SMS parts   in  storage 'sr'                                            
Locking SMS storages    to: mem1    (SR),   mem2    (none)...                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CPMS="SR"<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CPMS: 0,20,1,23,1,23<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                   
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  3   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CMGL=4<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   Setting messaging   unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB3)   Setting messaging   unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB2)   Enabling    messaging   unsolicited events  on  primary port                                    
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CNMI=2,1,2,1,0<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CMS   ERROR:  303<CR><LF>'                                                
Got failure code    303:00:00   Operation   not supported                                       
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CNMI=2,1,2,2,0<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   Messaging   unsolicited events  enabled on  primary                                     
(ttyUSB3)   Enabling    messaging   unsolicited events  on  secondary   port                                    
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
(ttyUSB3):  --> 'AT+CNMI=2,1,2,1,0<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB3):  <-- '<CR><LF>+CMS   ERROR:  303<CR><LF>'                                                
Got failure code    303:00:00   Operation   not supported                                       
(ttyUSB3):  --> 'AT+CNMI=2,1,2,2,0<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB3):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB3)   Messaging   unsolicited events  enabled on  secondary                                       
(ttyUSB3)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
Modem   has voice   capabilities,   enabling    the Voice   interface...                                    
(ttyUSB2)   Setting voice   unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB3)   Setting voice   unsolicited events  handlers                                            
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  2   (open)                                      
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CLIP=1<CR>'                                                     
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2):  --> 'AT+CRC=1<CR>'                                                      
(ttyUSB2):  <-- '<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'                                                        
(ttyUSB2)   device  open    count   is  1   (close)                                     
Modem   has time    capabilities,   enabling    the Time    interface...                                    
Modem   /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state   changed (enabling   ->  searching)                                      
Simple  connect state   (5/8):  Register
```

We had checked and compared the two syslog and found something.

If modem worked failed, the log would appear as below

```
Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (unknown -> searching)
```

If modem worked well, the log would appear as below

```
Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (unknown -> registering)
```

Between the two steps in log

(1)Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled

and

(2)Simple connect state (5/8): Register

We could not find any AT command about setting APN to LTE module.

Is there a network manager command or modem manager command to fix the issue?
Or I have to download modem manager source code and modify it for Japan case?

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably missing is the configuration of the "APN of the default LTE bearer". If the network in Japan requires a specific APN for the default LTE bearer, you would need that preconfigured even just to get registered in the network.

ModemManager has APIs to configure this, see [SetInitialEpsBearerSettings()](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Modem3gpp.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-ModemManager1-Modem-Modem3gpp.SetInitialEpsBearerSettings), but I'm afraid the API is not implemented for the specific case of your SIMCOM modem. The initial EPS bearer settings can only be changed in MBIM modems supporting it as of right now.

If you'd like to improve MM to add the SIMCOM-specific implementation needed for `SetInitialEpsBearerSettings()`, please do so and send the changes to upstream for review in the [fd.o gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager). Otherwise, you could build ModemManager using the `--with-at-command-via-dbus` configure option, so that you can send the AT commands you need via DBus using [Command()](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-ModemManager1-Modem.Command).